# Бот телеграм python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Я обучил его удалять ссылки, но мне нужно чтобы администратор группы который имеет username или userid смог присылать ссылки
Как это реализовать?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "hello")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.entities is not None and message.chat.id)
def delete_links(message):
    for entity in message.entities: 
        if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:           
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        else:
            return
bot.polling()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по вашесу коду, можно просто проверять, не пришло ли сообщение от пользователя с нужным `userid`

Comment: Попробовал это, бот работает исправно, не ругается после выполнения функции bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id, message.from_user.id!="842641816"), но все равно удаляет

Comment: Попробовал написать: если сообщения от userid находится не в юзерах, то удалить. В итоге не работает users_id = [842641816]
        if message.from_user.id not in users&entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
           
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)

Comment: Сделал так, все равно не работает
...
users_id = '842641816'


...
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.entities is not None and message.chat.id)
def delete_links(message):
    for entity in message.entities and message.from_user.id not in users:
     
        if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
         
           
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
           
        else:
            return

bot.polling()

Answer (score 1):

```
adm = [123, 456]  # список содержащий id администраторов

@bot.message_handler(regexp=r'https?://[^\s<>"]+|www\.[^\s<>"]+')
def delete_links(message):
    # if message.chat.type == 'supergroup' and message.from_user.id not in adm:
    if message.from_user.id not in adm:
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Comment: если потребуется расширить `regexp`, то поисковой запрос: _regex python url_